# Access Prompt won't unlock

Tags: password, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and every time Access Prompt, shows up it won't unlock even know I provide the right password. It will treat it as a wrong password.

Answer (score 1):

Before you treat it as a bad password, try CTRL-ALT-F1 and you should get a text-based login, verify your password is not working there. (one my box to get back to the graphical login I use CTRL-ALT-F7)

Failing that, can you connect via ssh from another machine and test out that password?

```
ssh username@hostname
```

You say you are providing the right password so try those things first.

Alternatively do you know the root password or have access? You can reboot and reset the password that way (maybe that's obvious not sure your knowledge level sorry)

Comment on how that works, please, or how you fixed it since this is a month old.

---

NOTE: 
There are several issues posted about a different problem with 15.10 not allowing/showing the text box to type in the password but it doesn't sounds like that here.

Having said that, when I worked for Apple doing tech support, we nearly invariable found that if you are typing in your password and it doesn't work, you are not typing it correctly. Granted your case honestly sounds like the exception.